# Split string to equal length substrings in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, split, substring

I have a string, for example "8FPHFW08" and I want to get these substrings: "8F000000", "00PH0000","0000FW00" , "00000008".

The relative python fuction is this:

```py
def split_str(s):
    res = []
    for i in range(0,len(s),2):
        a = ['0']*len(s)
        a[i:i+2] = s[i:i+2]
        res.append("".join(a))
    return res
```

This is my attempt but I need 0 in empty positions

```
function split_olc(olc) {   
    var splitted = []
    splitted.push(olc.match(/(..?)/g))
    console.log(splitted[0])
    return splitted[0]

}
```

How can I do the same thing in Javascript?

Comment: Have you tried writing any JavaScript code yet?  Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: yes, I put my code in js

Comment: Your JS "attempt" doesn't even try to re-create what Python is doing...

Comment: I just need a way to get that result, I don't care how. Are you here to help or criticize people?

Comment: We are here to help, but "just giving the code" isn't helping. Just like the old saying of giving a man a fish vs. teaching him to fish. Sometimes, however, you can give a man a fish AND teach him how to get more. That is why my answer provides the code, AND an explanation of what it does, in the hopes that your future endeavours go well. If I see you again, I'll be happy to help again, provided you've shown some effort and improvement :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript strings are immutable, so there's no fancy shortcut for "overwrite a substring with another substring". You have to `slice` it up yourself.

Start with a "template", a string of the appropriate length with all zeroes, then splice it and your subject string appropriately.

```
const template = s.replace(/./g,'0');
const res = [];
for( let i=0; i<s.length; i+=2) {
    res.push(
        template.substring(0, i)
        + s.substring(i, i+2)
        + template.substring(i+2)
    );
}
return res;
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is the best way to learn a new language, but I've tried to give you the best one-for-one translation of python to js of your code:

```js
function split_str(s) {                          // def split_str(s):
    const res = []                               // res = []
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i += 2) {      // for i in range(0,len(s),2):
        const a = new Array(s.length).fill('0'); //   a = ['0']*len(s)
        a.splice(i, 2, s[i], s[i+1]);            //   a[i:i+2] = s[i:i+2]
        res.push(a.join(''));                    //   res.append("".join(a))
    }
    return res;                                  // return res 
}

console.log(split_str('helloworld'))
```

Comment: I like this. Very nice. Sometimes, "translating" languages is easy. Just keep in mind that there may be other (better?) ways of achieving it in the target language.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yeah of course, but if you think in one language already it's easier to transition those patterns first than to learn a whole new set of patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Use `slice` to get the partial string. Use [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) and [`padEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd) fill the start and end with `0`

```js
function replace(str) {
  const len = str.length,
        output = []
        
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
    output.push(
      str.slice(i, i+2)
          .padStart(i+2, '0')
          .padEnd(len, '0')
    )
  }

  return output
}

console.log(
  ...replace("8FPHFW08")
)
```